# Can i disable <script> tag using css for media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css

while making a website that is only for desktop, and while viewing it on mobile I want an alert from browser to show that "not viewable in mobile!"
I have tried the following-

```
script {
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

but these didn't work even tried by putting class and script inside a div and then giving class and more. always the alert is showing at desktop view also!!
is there anyway possible?

Comment: I do not think CSS can affect JS being run. Try using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) instead, as it's like using a media query in JS.

Comment: Just use [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser), and if it is a mobile browser, don't execute the rest of the code

Comment: That will not work.

Comment: A `<script>` is already `display: none;` by default. There is no CSS property that affects `<script>` _execution_. That use case seems strange anyway. You mention media queries, so why not create a responsive design that works for both mobile and desktop? What is the difficulty with mobile? Seems like an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905).

Comment: How are you defining 'mobile' - viewport dimensions or some other capability?

Comment: It seems like you could check the view size, and then show your error message if it's less than... Can you supply more information? *What are you actually trying to accomplish?* Check out the link @SebastianSimon posted in their comment

Answer (score -1):

So if I'm reading this correctly you want to show something on mobile but hide it on desktop? If so this can be achieved using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hide-on-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-on-mobile">
  <p>Code to hide</p>
</div>
```

Comment: no, I want to disable script tag for mobile view